# How to add global css/scss in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

How can I add **global** CSS in nuxt 3?

Is there any CSS **property** like in nuxt 2?

**nuxt2.config**

```js
export default {
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.scss'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify global CSS in your `nuxt.config.ts|js` like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.scss',
  ],
})
```

See: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#css

Comment: The page has moved. New location: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#css